# Understanding the order of execution in a CSS stylesheet

Tags: css

Consider the following CSS stylesheet:

```
#start_experiment_button
{
  display: inline-block;
  color: black; 
  border: 3px outset gray; 
  background-color: #CCCCCC; 
  padding: 8px; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica; 
  font-weight: bold;
}


#start_experiment_button:hover 
{
  border: 3px inset gray; 
}


#start_experiment_button:active 
{
  border: 3px inset gray; 
}


#start_experiment_button
{
  display: none;
}
```

Notice that the `display` property of `#start_experiment_button` is defined twice.  Does this serve a purpose?  Does the second definition simply over-ride the first, such that the first need not have been written at all?  Or do the intervening definitions for `hover` and `active` somehow influence when the two `display` values take effect?

Comment: second will override the first one. i.e `display: none;`

Comment: You are essentially asking about specificity, which is a gnarly topic to grasp with CSS. Check out : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

Comment: This question has nothing to do with specificity, besides the fact that two equally specific selectors (heck, *two identical selectors*) are involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last rule

```
#start_experiment_button {
  display: none;
}
```

overrides the first one. Hence the element is not shown at all. Because the element is invisible both `:hover` and `:active` are not applied.

Note that as more specific the selector as higher priority the rule has. So if the element was visible the rules defined by the selectors  `#start_experiment_button:hover` and `#start_experiment_button:active` would have higher priority then the rule defined by `#start_experiment_button`.

Comment: accepting this answer because it was submitted first.

Answer (score 0):

> Does the second definition simply over-ride the first, such that the first need not have been written at all?

Yes, and only for the `display` property. The other properties are unaffected.

> Or do the intervening definitions for hover and active somehow influence when the two display values take effect?

No, they don't, because neither of those rules have their own `display` declarations, and even if they did, those states would be impossible to reach because the element is *never* rendered.

It's not clear why that last rule exists and why it appears in that spot unguarded by either a media query or a more qualified selector, because with its `display: none` declaration, it makes *all* the other three rules redundant by preventing the element from ever being rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it will override..

```
#start_experiment_button
{
  display: none;
}
```

This code will override your first code, as the code reads from first line to the last while its executed.. hope you got your answer..